# ¿como obtener valor de un array en String para compararlo en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array, string

Estoy intentando comparar el valor obtenido en una consulta, sin embargo no logra compararlo ya que muestra el error **"Undefined index: color "**

Consulta en el controlador

```
function obtenerColor($id)
{
    return $this->select("SELECT color FROM colores WHERE id = $id;");
}
```

Código PHP

```
<?php
require "../model/Model.php";
require "../control/Control.php";
$control = new Control();

$id = '100';
$color = 'Azul';

$dato = $control->obtenerColor($id);

if ($color==$dato['color']) { 
  echo 'hacer algo';
} else { 
  echo 'hacer otra cosa';
}
?>
```

El error al comparar que indica **"Undefined index: color "** esta en la línea de este código:

```
if ($color==$dato['color']) {
```

Al intentar imprimir el valor de la consulta para verificar:

```
echo print_r($dato, true);
```

Me imprime esto, lo que significa que si esta obteniendo el dato correctamente:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [color] => Azul ) )
```

**¿Como puedo obtener el valor 'Azul' del Array para poderlo comparar?**

ya intente con:

```
implode($dato);
$string = json_encode($dato);
$string = serialize($dato);
```

En todas sale una situación similar

Comment: `echo $dato[0]['color'];`

Comment: eres todo un crack, funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente:
tenemos un array dentro de otro, algo así

```
     $dato=array();

 $array2=array();
 $array2["color"]="Azul";

 $dato[0]=$array2;
 echo "<br>";//salto de línea
 var_dump($dato);//Ver el array
```

Para extraer el dato dentro del array $array2:

```
$pieza=$dato[0];//pieza guarda el array interno
$miColor=$pieza["color"];//miColor guarda lo que hay en el array pieza localidad color
echo "<br>". $miColor;//muestro lo que hay en miColor
```

Comment: - Con echo $dato['color']; me arroja Notice: Undefined index: color                              - Con echo $dato; me imprime                                                                                                       Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\blablabla on line 15
Array                                                                                                                           - Con echo $dato[0] la misma linea

Comment: Ahora qué te muestra con: var_dump($dato);

Comment: con var_dump($dato); me muestra esto: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["color"]=> string(4) "Azul" } }

Comment: Lo que esa línea te dice es que tiene un array con un dato array(1) y dentro de ese array en la posición 0    [0] hay otro array =>array(1) y dentro de ese array en la posición ["color"] hay un string de 4 caracteres string(4) con el valor Azul "Azul". Es decir el dato Azul está dentro de un array ese array está dentro de otro.

Comment: Si eso lo había deducido, lo que no he logrado es extraer ese dato 'Azul' y compararlo con mi variable Local $color que almacena de igual forma la palabra Azul, al compararlo y ser verdadero ejecuta X acción

Comment: Para extraer el dato:                                                                                                               $pieza=$dato[0];
$miColor=$pieza[0]; echo $miColor;                                                                                  Debería funcionar