# Obtener los datos almacenados en un array [resuelta]

Tags: php, array, wordpress

estoy raspando algunos datos de una tabla y necesito almacenarlos en un array para usarlos en otra parte del sistema.

Los datos de entrada vienen a través de `simple_html_dom.php`, más concretamente de una tabla.

Una vez obtenidos los datos, los paso a través de una función de reemplazo `str_replace` para filtrar un poco y después uso la función `preg_match_all` para extraer coincidencias de patrones (es decir, lo que me interesa).

Acá el código:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

# Separa los nombres con 'guion_bajo'
$the_title = rawurlencode(strtr(get_the_title(), ' ', '_'));
$html = file_get_html('https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/' . $the_title);

foreach ($html->find('table.infobox') as $tablePpal) {
    $tablePpal;
}
foreach ($tablePpal->find('table', 1) as $secondTable) {
    $cadena = strval($secondTable->plaintext);

    $filtrar = str_replace('í', 'i', $cadena);

    $regex = '/\d+[%]\s\w+\s[a]\s\w+/';
    $string = $filtrar;

    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $coincidencias, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($coincidencias[0]);
    print_r($coincidencias[1]);
    print_r($coincidencias[2]);
    print_r($coincidencias[3]);
    print_r($coincidencias[4]);
    print_r($coincidencias[5]);
    print_r($coincidencias[6]);
    print_r($coincidencias[7]);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Como se puede observar, accedo a cada valor por separado. Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 95% Forte a Fisico
)
Array
(
    [0] => 80% Forte a Terra
)
Array
(
    [0] => 45% Forte a Fogo
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100% Neutro a Morte
)
Array
(
    [0] => 105% Fraco a Energia
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100% Neutro a Sagrado
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90% Forte a Gelo
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100% Neutro a Cura
)
```

Acá lo que me interesa saber:

- ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de ese array? por ejemplo si quisiera obtener solamente **80% Forte a Terra** (texto limpio).

He intentado usando:

```
print_r($coincidencias[1]);
```

Pero obtengo:

```
// Resultado:
Array
(
    [0] => 80% Forte a Terra
)
```

Mi resultado ideal sería obtener el texto en un simple string:

**80% Forte a Terra**

Que podré usar más adelante en campos personalizados y/o en otras funciones con expresiones regulares.

¿Cómo puedo llegar a ese resultado?

Pregunta adicional:

- ¿Eso es un array asociativo?
- ¿Se le pueden cambiar los índices?

Answer (score 0):

### Solución:

```
echo $coincidencias[1]['0'];
```

[La encontré acá...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356145/como-obtener-valor-de-un-array-en-string-para-compararlo-en-php)